# Set union equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \ge  2$. Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ parts of a set.

How to show this equality ?

$$A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n=(A_1-A_2)\cup(A_2-A_3)\cup\cdots\cup(A_{n-1}-A_n)\cup(A_n-A_1)\cup(A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n)$$

Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $\subseteq$ direction, here's a hint. If $x \in A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_n$, then $x$ is in *at least* one of the sets $A_k$. Now either $x$ is in *all* of the sets $A_k$ or it isn't. If it isn't, let $1 \le k \le n$ be least such that $x \not\in A_k$. If $k>1$ then $x \in A_{k-1}$ but $x \not\in A_k$. If $k=1$ then you have a bit more work to do: in this case, either $x \in A_n$, in which case $x \in A_n - A_1$; or $x \not\in A_n$, in which case you need to consider now the *greatest* $\ell<n$ such that $x \in A_{\ell}$!

See if you can turn this into a proof.

The $\supseteq$ direction is (or should be) straightforward.

Comment: I think you have a minor mistake. If $k$ is the *least* such that $x\notin A_k$, then if $k>1$, we have $x\in A_{k-1}$. It isn’t necessarily the case that $x\in A_{k+1}$.

Comment: @Clayton So it should be more like ‘$x \in A_{k-1}$ so $x \in {A_{k-1} - A_k}$’, right?

Comment: Correct. If $x\in A_{k-1}$ and $x\notin A_{k}$, then $x\in (A_{k-1}-A_k)$.

Comment: @Clayton: Good catch, thank you! I'll edit my answer.